# Series converges for values of x $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2n^2-n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Determine the values of x for which the series converges $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2n^2-n}$

What I have tried:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{2n^2-n} \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n-1} \right)$

I know that comparatively $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$ converges for $-1 < x < 1$ and diverges for $|x| > 1$ so I'm assuming the same for the given series given the fractions of $\frac{1}{n}$.

Although I'm not 100% certain with my approach, what are some further ways of proofing this?

Comment: What is the radius of convergence ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I know that after taking the ratio test I get the following result $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x(2n-1)}{2n+3}$ when computing the limit this is 0 therefore it converges for all values of x?

Comment: Try again for the ratio test.

Comment: @GEdgar I have instead $\frac{xn(2n-1)}{(2n+1)(n+1)}$

Comment: So from this you get the radius of convergence.  Then investigate what happens if $|x|$ equals the radius of convergence.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm not too familiar with the radius of convergence, but when I set the limit to $\infty$ the series is equal to 0, how do I investigate for $|x|$?

Comment: @GEdgar My book mentions that it converges only when $x = a$, what does this mean?

Comment: In this case the radius of convergence is $1$.  That gives us convergence for $|x|<1$ and divergence for $|x|>1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series converges for $|x|<1$.
$\mathbf:-$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k(2k-1)}$$
$$2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$
For the last sum to converge it's obvious that $|x|<1$.
And for the sum, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{2k-1}$.
Let $x=u^{2}$ and multiply and divide by $u$.
We will have,
$$u\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{u^{2k-1}}{2k-1}$$
$$u (\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{u^{n}}{n}-\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{u^{2k}}{2k})$$
First sum converges for $|u|<1$ and second sum is also same. It can be seen by resubstituting $x=u^{2}$ back